# Node.js & node.io - iterating elements using "each" function stops server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function to handle http request and I need to scrap html page from given url. I just copied the example from [github](https://github.com/chriso/node.io). It works, it prints all found attributes but after that it prints "OK: Job complete" and shuts down the server. If I remove the each function, it doesn't stop the server, but I need to use it. Is this some bug in node.io (or in modules it uses) or am I doing something wrong?

```
function index(response, request){
require('node.io').scrape(function() {
    this.getHtml('http://www.reddit.com/', function(err, $) {
        var stories = [];
        $('a.title').each(function(title) {
            stories.push(title.text);
        });
        this.emit(stories);
    });
});
}
```

Edit: I've managed to do the job with jsdom, but I'm still wondering about this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user "derekdr" on GitHub, the solution for this is described [here](https://github.com/chriso/node.io/issues/35)